# constructor input arguments or hardcoded values? best practice

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-design

What is the rationale for choosing to use constructor input arguments over hardcoded values? and what is best practice?

Answer (score 0):

Constructors enable to reuse the smart contract without changing it.

Let's take the case of an ERC20 token with the following input parameters : `name`, `symbol`, `decimals`, `totalSupply`.
You can hardcode these values and deploy your contract, it will work fine.

Now suppose you need to deploy a new ERC20 with different input characteristics. Well, you will have to change the previous contract by modifying the input parameters.

Using a constructor prevents this : you can deploy as many ERC20 you want without touching your contract. You only have to change the deployment script.